# Generic type parameter with Record constraint gives unexpected errors

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Given this innocent-looking function,

```
// function what<T extends { [x: string]: number }>(
function what<T extends Record<string, number>>(
    obj: T
) {
    obj.key;     // okay
    obj.key = 2; // error?
}
```

TypeScript produces an error on the line `obj.key = 2`. You might expect the error to be in the same vein as:

```
// understandable
function ok<T>(t: T = 0) {}
//             ~~~~~~~~ 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'number'.
```

and that is indeed what [ms/TS#50873](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50873) brings up, but the error *is actually the following:*

> Property 'key' does not exist on type 'T'.

Sorry, what?! In the previous line, I have just used `obj.key` without a problem. At the very least, I'd expect the compiler to produce a similar error to the one in the second code snippet. If that wasn't enough, it seems that TypeScript knows that `obj.key` is a `number` of some sort. I can do arithmetic with it:

```
obj.key * 2 // still okay
```

However, when trying to assign a value, TypeScript says it's now `any`:

[image]

What's going on here? Why does TypeScript complain only when I try to assign a value to `obj.key` (and even emit the wrong error)?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.2#code/PTAEDMFcDsGMBcCWB7aoDuALAhvAPACqgCmAHvMdACYDOoA3qANqkBcoN8ATotAOYBddtEgBbAEbEuoAL4A+ABQAoKHCSoMOfETIVqdAErFYyLlTyce-ADSgREqXMVLQr0MnEArdgSUBKBhc3D08AOgBrYgBPAG43VxB3cOwooNcQiOjQAF5QACY4xKkuUwB+NPcvTKjQACp8hLBORAAbFqSUpRklJUSYKilObGpscRbiFRgEFDRkcMJFeB8c0AAGAPoZIA)

Comment: Looks like [ms/TS#47357](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47357) to me, which is acknowledged as a bug in the error *message*, but not in the existence of an error at all (which should probably be that `T["key"]` could be narrower than `number` so you can't assign it).  Does that fully address the question or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes @jcalz, that would do it. Out of curiosity, how do you find all these relevant issues? Is it just experience that you know what exactly to search for? I could not really find anything in the issues (hence, the Stack Overflow question).

Comment: I think perusing new issues as they come in for the last few years has given me an intuition for what to search for.  The worst is when I'm 100% sure I've seen the identical issue before but can't seem to find it when searching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same issue (or nearly so) as [microsoft/TypeScript#47357](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47357), which is marked as an error message bug.  It is observably apparent that you *can* index `T` with `"key"`, so  at best the error is misleading.

It's not that there should necessarily be no error at all; since `T extends Record<string, number>`, all we know is that `T["key"]` (if present) is some subtype of `number`, so while that's safely assignable *to* `number`, it could be an error for it to *accept* any particular number:

```
const arr = [, 2, "3"] as const;
const o = { key: 1 } as const;
console.log(arr[o.key].toFixed(2)); // "2.00"

what(o); 
o.key // 1 at compile time but 2 at runtime!
console.log(arr[o.key].toFixed(2)); //  RUNTIME ERROR!
```

It's still arguable whether or not there should definitely be an error, though; we know that TypeScript isn't perfectly sound, and if you change to a known key you get no error for the equivalent unsafe property write:

```
function hmm<T extends { key: number }>(obj: T) {
    obj.key = 2; // acceptable?!
}

what(o); 
o.key // 1 at compile time but 2 at runtime!
console.log(arr[o.key].toFixed(2)); //  RUNTIME ERROR!
```

It looks like sometimes generic objects are widened to their constraints when you index into them, as described in [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33181#issuecomment-526916194) on a similar issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#33181](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33181).  There's this tradeoff between treating generics as accurate-but-opaque types versus specific-but-approximate types, and while the heuristics followed by the compiler work well for a wide range of real-world code scenarios, there are still these unfortunate holes that you can fall through and barriers you can get stuck behind.

The above behavior with `T extends {key: number}` implies that if you really want to do that write you can always do so by explicitly widening the generic object to its constraint, to make the compiler err on the side of permissiveness:

```
function what<T extends Record<string, number>>(
    obj: T
) {
    const objSpecific: Record<string, number> = obj; // okay
    objSpecific.key = 2; // okay
}
```

Anyway, whether or not the presence of an error is desirable, we can at least say that the particular error message wording is, according to microsoft/TypeScript#47357, a bug.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.2#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)